# VirtualBox host key stops working

Tags: ubuntu, virtualbox, virtual-machine

I'm running an Ubuntu virtual machine on a Ubuntu host on my laptop.
A majority of the time when I switch from my host to my virtual machine (full screen) the host key stops working. Now that I'm in full screen on my virtual machine, I can't switch back to my host. So I have to shut down my virtual machine and restart it.

After restarting everything works fine until the next switch to full screen. Do you have any suggestions about what's wrong? …

Comment: This happens to me as well, quite frequently, often times I just end up pressing the host key (right ctrl) multiple times and it boots out of it. I have my VM in a "space" and only access it with keyboard shortcuts for navigating spaces (ctrl + alt + arrow key). Next time it happens maybe try hitting ctrl multiple times and see if it gets you out of there. I would love to know how to make this 100% reliable.

Comment: What are you using for your host key?

Comment: I've had this happen with the VM fullscreen on one monitor (Ubuntu guest, Win7 host); once, it trapped my mouse and both keyboards in the VM; but usually, only one keyboard gets stuck inside the VM, and I can save-state and reload the VM to fix it.

Comment: This seems to happen to me only when I try to lock the host without first switching to another window (other than the VM). Somehow, the keyboard gets stuck inside the VM, even at the lock-screen window.